# PySide / PyQtGraph access to main Qt event thread

Tags: python, pyside, pyqtgraph

the attached program throws these errors:

QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread

QObject::startTimer: timers cannot be started from another thread

```
import sys
import PySide
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
import threading

from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *
from ui_mainWindow import Ui_MainWindow

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Main Window Class
# handle events and updates to the Qt user interface objects
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setup_actions()
        self.show()

    def setup_actions(self):
        self.startScopeButton.clicked.connect(self.start_stop_scope)

    def start_stop_scope(self):
        print("starting scope")
        self.scope_display_thread()

    def scope_display_thread(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self._scope_display_thread).start()

    def _scope_display_thread(self):
        global data_ch1      
        data_ch1  = np.random.normal(0, 10, 1000)
        self.graphicsView.plot(data_ch1,clear=True)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Main Application Start Point
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    ret = app.exec_()
    sys.exit( ret )

data_ch1 = []
main()
```

This is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do .. namely have one thread receive and plot data. From searching the forums etc. I know fundamentally the problem is that I have to update the plot from the "main Qt event thread" .. but I don't know how to accomplish this. Several signal-slot permutations of my code seemed promising but only caused the program to crash.

Please go easy on me, I'm a reformed C# person ;-) In C# or Java normally I'd actually do the drawing in a paint method override, and then just force the application to repaint when new data was loaded in. It seems that PyQtGraph.plot() tried to paint right away?? Can I add data asynchronously and then tell the main thread to go repaint the scene??

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As you comment on your question you can only update the GUI in the main thread, then the strategy for this type of problems is to send the data of the secondary thread to the main through signals.

The signals can carry several data, but these must be indicated in its creation, the way to create it is the following:

```
signal = QtCore.Signal(type_1, type_2, ..., type_n)
```

In your particular case `np.random.normal (0, 10, 1000)` is `np.ndarray`, this can easily be obtained by executing the following:

```
print(type(np.random.normal (0, 10, 1000)))
```

Output:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Or we can use `object` since all classes inherit from that base class. Then we connect that signal with the function that plots, in this case we will use a lambda function as shown below:

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    signal = QtCore.Signal(np.ndarray) # or signal = QtCore.Signal(object)

    def __init__(self):
        [..]
        self.show()

        self.signal.connect(lambda data: self.graphicsView.plot(data, clear=True))

    [...]

    def _scope_display_thread(self):
        data_ch1 = np.random.normal(0, 10, 1000)
        self.signal.emit(data_ch1)
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the help. I have a feeling this will help others as well. It was a bit of a wild goose chase for me to find the correct method even though I understood the basic problem.